# How to restrict components in parsys

Tags: aem

Is there a way in CQ 5.6 to restrict use of specific components within a parsys? e.g. I want to restrict author to use only text component within a parsys, following is how I render the parsys inside one of my component JSP file:

```
<cq:include path="textpar" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

Previously in CQ 5.4 following code in /etc/designs/myapp/.content.xml used to work for this:

```
<textpar
    jcr:lastModified="{Date}2012-10-21T15:00:00.000-07:00"
    jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"
    components="[/libs/foundation/components/text]">
    <section jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
```

But in CQ 5.6 it's not working. Am I missing something or the way to restrict components changed?

Thanks

Comment: I just double checked with the Geometrixx example.  The xml has not changed.  Looks like you are doing it correctly.  Perhaps something else is going on. Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This actually works. There's seems to be some cache issue on my machine though, whenever I change something in /etc/designs/myapp/.content.xml I've to clear my cache to get the updated components, this is on FF 25 (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very easy tutorial on setting default types for parsys and iparsys:

http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/06/default-components-in-your-parsys.html